# Is the engineer the closest class to the Shaman?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've always loved shaman classes, was a shaman in WoW. Sad to say there is no Shaman class in GW2 but is the engineer the closest class like it?

Comment: Could you include some more detail in your question, specifically what elements about the Shaman you like? It would result in more detailed answers for your question.

Answer (score 7):

If by 'Like the Shaman' you're referring specfically to Totems, then yes, in a way. Engineer turrets are similar to Totems, but you won't get as much variety as a Shaman did, although there's a decent selection:

Healing turret heals you, and can be overcharged to remove debuffs.

Rifle turret shoots. That's all.

Flame turret shoots at shorter range, it probably sets enemies on fire.

Net turret snares enemies.

Thumper turret does AoE damage around it, and may be a more appealing target to mobs. It might have a knockdown ability on overcharge.

Sadly, turrets are somewhat lacklustre at the moment, and Engineer in general is weaker than other classes due to a lack of focus and some design issues, although they were reworked for the upcoming beta event.

On the other hand, if by Shaman you meant "PUNCH PEOPLE IN THE FACE WITH LIGHTNING", go Elementalist.

Comment: More on Engineer.http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Engineer